# Contributing to elementary OS team

Tags: development, elementary-project

I've been using elementary OS Freya for almost a year and recently switched to Loki, which is much better in every aspect.
As a daily user of the OS, I see areas where I feel that some features can be added.
Where can I post my ideas so that the team will see or at least answer me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can propose your aditionals features to the dev team going to [Blueprints section at elementary OS Launchpad](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/elementaryos)

You can also navigate through the various applications pages at Launchpad and propose new features in its blueprint section. To know all of them,  you can visit the metaproject page at https://launchpad.net/elementary

Answer (score 0):

To add, you can also contribute with money (the devs will definitely appreciate it):

- giving a small amount of money monthly via [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/elementary/).
- placing bounties on open issues via [BountySource](https://www.bountysource.com/teams/elementary).